# Disconnecting load circuit from reference [current mirrors]

Tags: analog, switching, current-mirror, chip-design

I have started learning microelectronics design and I am currently working on my bachelor thesis. There's one thing I wanted to ask you about current mirrors and its switching.

My thesis is mainly focused on converting sensor's changing resistance to current, then to frequency. Firstly, I charge the capacitor with constant current and then discharge it with constant current as well. During the discharging, I want to turn off the current mirror responsible for charging the capacitor.

Problem is, I have tried placing PMOS transistor in parallel with my PMOS current mirror, but it turned off my reference part of the mirror as well (which has to be active all the time).

Some of you may say: ,,Why don't you just put PMOS transistor in series with your load part of the circuit and control it that way?" Yes, it may be possible, but when the switch opens, the current mirror tries to push the current through infinite load and it creates voltage spike until it settles. So I discarded that idea.

I will show you the diagram so you can better understand my problem (blue part has to be disconnected).

[image]

If I explained something incorrectly, I would be glad if you showed me the right way to do it. I am willing to learn all the time :). Any opinion will be gladly received.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, you are trying to have a single terminal (Isens) that can both source and sink a constant (or controllable) current to & from a capacitor.  I suspect a solution already exists, and rather than reinvent the wheel, I would suggest considering the solution already embodied within an existing product, here is one example: the L6599AT from ST.  Relevant parts of the datasheet are copied here below for your convenience.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a PMOS between Isens and your load, and another PMOS between Isens and ground? Invert the gate drive between them. This doesn't shut down the mirror, but steers its current to ground when you don't want it going to the load.